# Samsung store and Google Play - Android Apk

Tags: android, google-play, apk, publish, samsung-mobile

I have a free app available on Google Play. I would like to publish the same apk on Samsung store but it seems the guidelines for samsung store has changed from July 1st. Does any one has idea on following:
1. Can I publish my apk as is on Samsung store or do I need to re-develop the app using samsung sdk and then push it to samsung store?
2. If i need to re-develop app then is there any migration guide available?

Regards,
SS